# Kotlin function "no value passed for parameter 'name'"

Tags: kotlin

[Problems with Kotlin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqi10.png)

I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I was expecting the String declarations to turn purple for one.

Also, I don't know how to pass the value.

I've tried moving my input to different places but keep getting errors, mostly the one i've shared.

Comment: I don't know how the error message could be more clear.  Your `birthdayGreeting` requires that you pass it a name as a parameter.  You're not passing anything.  You can't just call `birthdayGreeting()`.  That's an error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `birthdayGreeting()` function without the 'name' parameter in the last line of your code. Just pass some string to this function.